# Remove hostednetwork password

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, command-line, windows-8.1, netsh

I've set up my own Nintendo HomePass relay to get StreetPass from home, but recently something has changed and it doesn't work anymore. I've read I have to change some settings to make it work again, and I need to remove the password of my *hosted network*.

I know how to change hosted network settings:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<mySSID> key=<password>
```

But I don't know the command to remove the current key, or how to set the network as free. Or the command to delete the previous saved network, in order to set up a new one without the `key` attribute.

Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for an answer to this myself when I found your question. After reading the comments in harrymc's answer, I decided to test some things out myself. I found one way that was surprisingly simple, yet did exactly what you wanted:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<mySSID> key=
```

That command is no mistake, you just don't add anything after the "key=", and it will be empty.

You can also verify that the password is gone by using this command:

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork security
```

The above command should show have something similiar to the line below:

> User security key : <Not specified>

However, it should be noted that you can never leave the SSID blank. You will also not be able to have a SSID that has one or more spaces in it using the first command given. To do so, you must instead parse the command like so:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<mySSIDwithSpaces> && netsh wlan set hostednetwork key=
```

Comment: Thank you, I have to try this. I don't need this anymore, but +1 for your help.

Comment: can you please tell me how to create an "Open Network ( without password )" using netsh command..?

Comment: As @LoveToCode implied, leaving the key empty still creates a connection using WPA2 personal. On my Android phone it's still asking me for a password, and it does not accept an empty one.

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods to delete a hosted network.

**Method 1 : Network and Sharing Center**

Right click on the Network icon in the notification area ([image]) and
choose "Network and Sharing Center".

In the Network and Sharing Center windows, click on "Change Adapter settings",
to see all of your network connections. This will look like:

[image: image2]

Select the Hosted Network and press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button, then restart your PC.

**Method 2 : Command-line to delete the virtual adapter**

Open the Command Prompt with Administrator rights and enter the following command:

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
```

You will receive a message confirming that the wireless hosted network stopped.
However it is not yet disabled.
In order to disable it, enter this command:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow
```

The result is the message "The hosted network mode has been set to disallow".
You'll also notice that the virtual adapter is no longer listed in the Network and Sharing Center.

Furthermore, if you want to double-check the status of the hosted network, you can run the following command:

```
netsh wlan show settings
```

It should say : "Hosted network mode allowed in WLAN service: No".

**Method 3 : Command-line to delete/forget one network**

Start the Command Prompt as administrator and type the following command :

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

It will display all the wireless network profiles stored by Windows 8.1. The list can be long if you used your laptop or tablet for more than a couple of weeks :

[image: image3]

Identify the name of the wireless network profile you want removed, then type the following command to remove it:

```
netsh wlan delete profile name="swisscom"
```

**Method 4 : Command-line to delete/forget all networks**

In some scenarios you may need to remove all the wireless network profiles stored in Windows 8.1. 
This is done using this command:

```
netsh wlan delete profile name=* i=*
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway my original problem was how to remove the passkey from a custom network, but I've found that Windows doesn't allow me to remove WPA encryption, so I think there's no solution (correct me if I'm wrong). So I should accept your answer.

Comment: I have searched for a method of removing the passkey, but have found none. I found instead several methods of removing the network, as listed above. Removing and recreating the network should have the same result.

Comment: I don't think so, I believe it will always have a default passkey.

Comment: @pinckerman: I also tend to think that it's probably impossible to create a hosted network without any passphrase at all, but I have never tried.

Comment: You may be right. I'll wait for eventual other answers, then I'll award you the bounty.